# Redux Toolkit configuration, is it correct for full stack app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to the redux toolkit, but after long research, I managed to write this configuration for the redux toolkit to fetch data from my backend express API. Can anyone please guide me if I am going right?

Should I use createAsyncThunk or this configuration is also correct?

***store.js***

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import productReducer from "./features/productSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productReducer,
  },
});
```

***productSlice.js***

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    startLoading: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    hasError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
    allProductsSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.products = action.payload;
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

***productActions.js***

```
import axios from "axios";
import { productsSlice } from "./productSlice";

const { allProductsSuccess, startLoading, hasError } = productsSlice.actions;

export const fetchProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startLoading());
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");

    dispatch(allProductsSuccess(data.products));
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch(hasError(e?.response?.data?.message));
  }
};
```

***Home.js (Component)***

```
const { products, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
console.log(products, isLoading)

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(fetchProducts());
}, []);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it correct? Sure, it looks like it would compile and run and do what you want.

Is it the recommended implementation? Not exactly. Using the [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) utility you can cut down on a little of the boilerplate/repetitive code. You can effectively "merge" the `productSlice.js` and `productActions.js` files since all the related actions can be exported from the `productSlice.js` file. `createAsyncThunk` generates the "pending"/"success"/"error" actions for you.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchProducts = createAsyncThunk(
  "products/fetchProducts",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/products");

      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(e?.response?.data?.message);
    }
  }
);

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchProducts.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.products = action.payload.products;
        state.isLoading = false;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProducts.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.error = action.payload;
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
});

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Hi @Drew, thanks for your answer. This means that I have to these 3 cases (pending, fulfilled, rejected) to all actions? And should I create separate file for each action like, get all products in one file and get single product in second file and so on?

Comment: @robert_45 Only `createAsyncThunk` actions generate these three actions, and you only need to use the actions you need. How you split your state up is largely up to you. I generally keep related state together in the same slice, but a case could be made for separating them. If you keep `product` state in this same slice then you can use a [matching utility](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities) to handle multiple actions with a single reducer case, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Is there an article or tutorial that can help me manage multiple actions? I am a bit confused with the structure, I would really appreciate it if you can provide me with any resources.

Comment: @robert_45 Do you mean something *other than* the official docs? I've already linked to relevant documentation. I'm not sure what you would need help with with multiple actions.